# How to search in vector with If and else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector

I have an issue with searching in a vector. Let's say I have a vector, the idea is to use if and else statements to check each element and then print out a string message. So for example if there is a 1 at 0 then it should print out a message. The example below shows what I am trying to explain. If there is 1 at 0 then print out a message.

```
vector<int> myvec {1,2,3,4,5};

if (statement) {
  cout << "The number 1 is at 0";
}
```

At the moment I have tried this:

```
vector<int> myvec {1,2,3,4,5};

if (find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 3) != myvec.end()) {
  cout << "yes it is there" << endl;
}
```

This only checks to see if 3 is in the vector but I want to find out if 1 is at 0.

Comment: why not just `if (myvec.at(0) == 1) {...}`?

Comment: @maany if ( !myvec.empty() && myvec[0] == 1 ) { /* output a messsage */ }

Comment: Thanks guys the answer is right in front of me the whole time‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying too hard, simply

```
if (myvec[0] == 1)
```

For extra security you could add a check that the vector is not empty

```
if (!myvec.empty() && myvec[0] == 1)
```

Comment: I'd suggest `myvec.size() > 0` because that generalizes to other elements. I.e. `myvec[42]` exists if and only if `.size() > 42`.